# how Create program using binary in CUDA?

Tags: cuda, opencl, hpc, pycuda

I had code in OpenCL where I use clCreateProgramWithBinary() to create the program from binary.
I am porting this application to CUDA and I don't find any similar function.

Can someone help me with how I can create the program from binary or equivalent of clCreateProgramWithBinary in CUDA?

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, the CUDA equivalent of `clCreateProgramWithBinary()` will be `cuModuleLoad ()`. Please check `cuModuleLoad ()` for precompiled binary. It loads a compute module.

For further reference please check module management in [CUDA Driver API API Reference Manual](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/CUDA_Driver_API.pdf).